# Who closed the browser tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I've got a (WebRTC) web application runs across three tabs:

- Tab 1 resets the database (deleting any existing data, recreating initial data set)
- Tab 2 acts as a client #1, sending asynchronous requests to the server
- Tab 3 acts as a client #2, sending asynchronous requests to the server

What I've noticed is that if I reload Tab 1, one or both of the other tabs close themselves (as in, removed from the list of tabs in Chrome). I asked  Chrome developers on IRC and they insist that Chrome will print "Aw snap!" in case of a tab crash but will not remove it from the list of tabs. I am fairly certain my own code isn't closing the page.

**How can I figure out what/who is closing the tab?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel retarded.

So, days of investigating this issue I discovered that my code was invoking a function in case of a network error and this function was invoking `close()`. Instead of resolving to my class' `close()` method, it resolved to `window.close()` instead. Guess what happened next? :) The tab closed.

What made this problem particularly difficult were two Chrome-specific bugs:

- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170757
- http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170760

In short: `window.close()` works when it shouldn't, and when it fails it does so silently.

Anyway, I consider this matter closed. I hope this helps others avoid making the same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Javascript or Chrome, but I've been doing some socket programming lately and if the Server goes down, the Clients typically crash unless they realize that the Server dropped the connection and handle that (try/catch statements). My advice would be to make sure that your Clients are able to handle the Server dropping out on them.

Comment: I've never seen uncaught exceptions cause a tab to close.